# Issue Clicking on Array Thumbnails for full-size Image, with Next and Previous buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have figured out how to have my background images be replaced with the click of a button, but now I want to have thumbnail images in a "gallery" that you can click on  as well.  I've figured out how to get the images to change with the click of a "next" and "previous" button, but whenever I try to also incorporate clicking on the thumbnails, it really messes things up.  Basically, I want to be able to click on a thumbnail and change the index number so when you hit the "next" button, it goes to the next image in line, whereas before it was going back to the 2nd image in line, regardless of what thumbnail you had clicked on.  I've only included the "next image" function for brevity.

The issue is that when I click on the thumbnail, it goes to the right image, but then if you hit the "next" button, it just goes to the second image, regardless of whether you were on the 7th image, the 5th, etc.  So, basically, I don't know how to get the next image function to read the index number of the current image.

Thank you!!!

```
//beginning of the whole background slideshow function
$(function() {

//setting the arrays
var colorBackgrounds = new Array(
'url(backgrounds/photoTest/20140714-_MG_0604.jpg)',
'url(backgrounds/photoTest/20140714-_MG_0860.jpg)',
'url(backgrounds/photoTest/20140716-IMG_1296.jpg)'
);
 var backgroundThumbs = new Array(
'/backgrounds/photoTest/20140714-_MG_0604_TN.jpg)',
'/backgrounds/photoTest/20140714-_MG_0860_TN.jpg)',
'/backgrounds/photoTest/20140716-IMG_1296_TN.jpg)'
);

 var colorCurrent = 0;
 var tnCurrent = 0;

//populating the div with the thumbnails & click function (works)
 backgroundThumbs.forEach(function(value,index) {
    $('#thumbID_' + index).html('<img src="' + value + '" class="thumbImage" />');
    $('#thumbID_' + index).click(function() {
        var tnCurrent = index;
        var colorCurrent = tnCurrent;
    $('.bodyBackground').fadeOut(500, function() { 
        $('.bodyBackground').css({
            'background':colorBackgrounds[colorCurrent],
            'background-position':'center center',
            'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
            'background-attachment':'fixed'});
            $('.bodyBackground').fadeIn(500);           
        }); 
    });
});

//beginning of nextBackground function (works, but doesn't take into account thumbnail click changes)
$('.nextImageWrapper').click(function() {
    $('.bodyBackground').fadeOut(500, function() { 
        $('.bodyBackground').css({
            'background':colorBackgrounds[colorCurrent = ++colorCurrent % colorBackgrounds.length],
            'background-position':'center center',
            'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
            'background-attachment':'fixed'});
            $('.bodyBackground').fadeIn(500);

    }); 
});
```

Comment: you already defined `colorCurrent` and `tnCurrent` in global scope. You should reference it inside and not define again. That might be the problem.

Comment: Well, they're actually inside another function, so they're not truly global, right?  So should I make them global and then call them back inside the variable using getElementById and alert?  This is where I show how inexperienced I am with some of this!

Comment: They are actually global. What you are doing is you are defining them inside `document ready function`, i.e., when the document is ready, then you are assigning something to those variables, whereas `forEach` function is different. Inside that, you would want to reference those and not define them once again. Then check if your problem has solved.

Comment: Ahhh...  I understand the problem -  I'll just move the variables outside this function so that they are global, then see if I can reference them and see what happens.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {

 var colorCurrent = 0;
 var tnCurrent = 0;

 // rest code

backgroundThumbs.forEach(function(value,index) {

 // rest code    

 tnCurrent = index;
 colorCurrent = tnCurrent;

 // rest code

});

});
```

See if that works.

Comment: I just did that, and it works, except that when you click the "nextImage" button, it now skips TWO images.  I tried     
   " colorCurrent = tnCurrent - 1; "
    and that works, but only for the first time, and then after that it skips again.  Very frustrating - I thought I had it licked!

Comment: I figured it out - I added the operators into the beginning of the  next and previous functions  and then just referenced that in the css changer.  It works great!

Comment: That's great. I knew you were having problems with referencing somehow. Apart from that the code looked okay.